# Why do I have empty rows when I create a CSV file?

Tags: python, csv

Im trying to create a new csv file which evaluates data about a construction site operation from an ASCII table in CSV format file.  I have figured out how to create a CSV file, but I always get a blank line between the lines. Why is that?

```
import csv

header = ['name', 'area', 'country_code2', 'country_code3']
data = ['Afghanistan', 652090, 'AF', 'AFG']

file_object = open("new_file.csv", "w")
writer = csv.writer(file_object, delimiter=";")
writer.writerow(header)
writer.writerow(data)
file_object.close()
```

that how my csv file looks like:

```
name   area   country_code2   country_code3

Afghanistan   652090   AF   AFG
```

Comment: I ran your code and got no empty lines.  Is there something not included in the code you've shown?

Comment: This is the only code in my pthon file. The first line starts with the header, the second line is empty and the third line starts with data.

Comment: Since I am creating a new CSV file I have not read it yet.

Comment: Try option newline=''

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specify `newline=''` to eliminate the extra new line.

If newline='' is not specified on platforms that use \r\n linendings on write an extra \r will be added. It should always be safe to specify newline='', since the csv module does its own ([universal](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-universal-newlines)) newline handling. [[1]](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#id3)

```python
with open('new_file.csv', 'w', newline='') as file_object:
    writer = csv.writer(file_object, delimiter=";")
    writer.writerow(header)
    writer.writerow(data)
```

Comment: It works Thank you. What was the error? It is correct in itself what I have done or?

Comment: No error per say. Just a strange nuance in Python on Windows platforms. See [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#id3).